# RestSharp updating use of AddHandler method to use factory delegate

Tags: c#, restsharp

The latest version of RestSharp v106.6.9 apparently makes some changes making the overrides of the AddHandler method of a Request obsolete such as this signature:

```
[Obsolete("Use the overload that accepts a factory delegate")]
public void AddHandler(IDeserializer deserializer, params string[] contentTypes)
```

As it suggest to use the factory delegate form

```
public void AddHandler(string contentType, Func<IDeserializer> deserializerFactory)

public void AddHandler(Func<IDeserializer> deserializerFactory, params string[] contentTypes)
```

Would anyone be able to point me to an example of implementing this.
Or explain how to transform my use of a customSerializer implementing IDeserializer below, to a factory delegate:

```
RestClient.AddHandler("application/json", CustomJsonSerializer.Instance);


public class CustomJsonSerializer : IDeserializer
{
    public static CustomJsonSerializer Instance => new CustomJsonSerializer();

    public string ContentType
    {
        get => "application/json";
        set { } // maybe used for Serialization?
    }

    public string DateFormat { get; set; }

    public string Namespace { get; set; }

    public string RootElement { get; set; }

    public T Deserialize<T>(IRestResponse response) => RestSharpResponseHandlers.DeserializeObject<T>(response);
}
```

Comment: Whenever you call `Instance`, you'll get a new `CustomJsonSerializer` instance. Is this on purpose? Why not remove the getter (and instead use a normal field instantiation), and use the same instance during whole app lifetime?

Comment: Since this was ultimately called only once in the constructor of the RestSharpClient, in the end only using one would have been better

Comment: I mean check the `AddHandler` part below in the following webpage: https://www.bytefish.de/blog/restsharp_custom_json_serializer.html . For every `AddHandler` they instantiate a new serializer. Wouldn't it be better to instantiate once and give that same instance to every `AddHandler`?

Comment: Yes you're right, it could have been written better.
What i meant was that while making this post, i wasn't sure of the lifespan of this custom serializer and was thinking it might get garbage collected, but in the end i too added it once in the constructor and used that single instance once for the entire lifespan...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to the source code at https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/dev/src/RestSharp/RestClient.cs:

```
 [Obsolete("Use the overload that accepts a factory delegate")]
 public void AddHandler(string contentType, IDeserializer deserializer) =>
    AddHandler(contentType, () => deserializer);
```

The obsolete overload just calls the `AddHandler(string contentType, Func<IDeserializer> deserializerFactory)` overload.

So you can replace your code to add your custom handler as follows:

```
RestClient.AddHandler("application/json", () => { return CustomJsonSerializer.Instance; });
```

Comment: @sparkplug updated my code based on your examples and it worked for my upgrade of that method.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem.  It looks like the OpenAPI code is setting mulitple handlers for multiple context types, so I wrote this little function

```
        private void AddHandlerHelper(RestClient client, IDeserializer deserializerFactory, string[] contextTypes)
        {
            foreach( var contextType in contextTypes)
            client.AddHandler(contextType,() => deserializerFactory);
        }
```

And the the call changes from this:

```
client.AddHandler(() => existingDeserializer, "application/json", "text/json", "text/x-json", "text/javascript", "*+json");
```

to this

```
AddHandlerHelper(client, existingDeserializer, new string[] { "application/json", "text/json", "text/x-json", "text/javascript", "*+json"});
```

There are six places in the generated code I needed the function.

Comment: Found out that OpenAPI actually had a newer generator, but before I did, made a nice little extension method with your sample - left credit to this post.  Thanks!

https://gist.github.com/TWhidden/ef18431a02d586ddc6ed76f2eeaa6d22